# codigo 256 ejecutando os.system

Tags: python, ubuntu, modulos

estoy intentando ejecutar un modulo dentro de otro modulo en python utilizando os.system con el adicional que devo enviarle dos argumentos y me arroja Código 256.

```
import os
os.system(f'/post-record.py {Name} {Folder}')
```

alguien de buen Corazon que me pueda ayudar, gracias

Comment: Utiliza el módulo `subprocess` ahí tienes varias opciones como `run`, `Popen`, etc.

Comment: ¿El archivo post-record.py? está en la raíz del disco? ¿El archivo post-record.py está marcado como ejecutable?

Comment: los dos módulos están al mismo nivel en jerarquía de archivos y el archivo post-record.py no esta marcado como ejecutable si te refieres al __init__main o lago asi